# Find all lines in a file with a certain character at a certain position

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a lab question asking me to use `grep` with a regex pattern to match every word where the third letter from the beginning of the line is an "a" and save it with a redirect. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

The solution proposed by @rahmu is simple if you look for low positions, but what if you look for the character number 25? Put in 25 dots?

In such a case the following solutions could be at hand. With `grep`

```
grep '^.\{24\}a' input >output
```

With `awk`

```
awk -F '' '$25 == "a"' input >output
```

Answer (score 4):

This should answer your question:

```
grep -e "^..a" < input > savefile
```

Comment: Nice and simple solution. I don't think `-e` is even needed here - like `grep ^..a < input > output` should suffice.